# Instantiate an observable in RxJs by providing an async executor

Tags: rxjs

I want to do the following but it is not possible because of the types that the Observable constructor expects.

```
const fetchData = async (observer: Observer<ViewState<...>>): Promise<void> => {
  observer.next(loading())

  const response = await ... // fetch data

  if (response.type === ResponseType.FAILURE) {
    observer.next(fail())
  } else {
    observer.next(loaded(response.data))
  }
}

...

const obs = new Observable(fetchData)
const subscription = obs.subscribe(...)
```

The problem is that the Observable constructor asks the executor a return type of `TeardownLogic` which cant be `Promise<T>`.

Is there a proper or standard way of doing this?

What i did is to create something like this helper builder function:

```
export const buildObservableFromAsyncExecutor = <T>(
  executor: (subscriber: Observer<T>) => Promise<void>
): Observable<T> => {
  const subject = new Subject<T>()
  executor(subject) // not awaiting the Promise

  return subject.asObservable()
}

...

const obs = buildObservableFromAsyncExecutor(fetchData)
const subscription = obs.subscribe(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something like this:

```
const fetchData = async (observer: Observer<ViewState<...>>): Promise<void> => {
  observer.next(loading())

  const response = await ... // fetch data

  if (response.type === ResponseType.FAILURE) {
    observer.next(fail())
  } else {
    observer.next(loaded(response.data))
  }
}

...

const obs = new Subject<ViewState<...>>()
const subscription = obs.subscribe(...)
await fetchData(obs)
```